# iOS: What can cause the Xcode compiler to throw errors when I include my AppDelegate.h into another header file?

Tags: objective-c, ios, compiler-construction, import

I am trying to #import my "AppDelegate.h" into another header file of the same project in order to access methods of the AppDelegate of my iOS project.

So, my header file looks something like this:
    #import

```
#import "DataProvider.h"
#import "MyAppDelegate.h"

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate> {
...
}
```

and I want to use my AppDelegate like this:

```
MyAppDelegate* appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
[appDelegate doSomething];
```

However, as soon as I #import "MyAppDelegate.h", the compiler throws a lot of (unrelated) errors, like

```
Cannot find interface declaration for 'MyOtherViewController', superclass of 'MyOtherViewController2'
```

The thing is: I can include my AppDelegate just fine in other headers. And I cannot figure out what the difference might be. Please help me figure out what could cause this! Thanks a lot!

PS: This happens with GCC as well as the new LLVM.

Comment: can you post MyAppDelegate.h ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move the #import into the .m file.  If you need the MyAppDelegate symbol in your .h, use `@class MyAppDelegate;` instead.

Comment: @cit: i believe this answer will absolutely solve your problem :)

Comment: Now: why did the #import in the header make the compiler go wild? Just curious...

Comment: You'd have to inspect the headers to get full details but the general idea is that something in the app delegate header depended on something in the view controller header and vice versa...therefore the imports were essentially circular.

Comment: Thankyou folkes that was the problem. What it did do was open the door to other trivial errors I had with my code which keen eyed IOS programmers may spot. I wish the compiler was more precise, its now 2013. How come the answer was accepted, but not by me?

Comment: But Why and what happens here?